# Sending json and file(binary) together by requests() of python

Tags: python, django, request

I have this curl command which send file and data to my api.

It works correctly.

```
curl --location 'localhost:8088/api/' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--form 'file=@"image.png"' \
--form 'metadata="{
    \"meta\": {
        \"number\": 400
    }}"'
```

Now I want to do the equivalent thing to inside of the python.

So I use `requests` however it says `TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'`

How can I do when sending the json and image data together?

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
metadata = {"number":400}
response = requests.post('https://localhost:8088/api/',
     headers=headers, data={
        metadata:metadata},
        file = {
            open("image.png",'rb')
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the binary data to base64 and add them as a field of your JSON.

```py
import base64
image_b64 = base64.b64encode(open('image.png', 'rb').read())

data = {
   "metadata": {"number": 400},
   "file": image_b64,
}
response = requests.post(
   'https://localhost:8088/api/', 
   headers=headers,
   data=data,
)
```

Comment: I tried this but api (FastAPI) returns 200 but `{"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}`

Comment: Well, it is likely that this is not what the API expects. Do you have a control over the backend you query against, or is it a third party?

Answer (score 0):

in `requests` library the correct argument for `file` is `files`

use something like this

```py
import requests

files = {'media': open('test.jpg', 'rb')}

requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it also helpful but my goal is sending file with json